# How can I separate model on multiple .js files in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

Can I separate model custom logic on different .js files, for example:

```
/common/models/
... MyMode.js
... MyModel.hooks.js
... MyModel.validations.js
... MyModel.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out;

require the other files and call them inside the main model.js file

```
let validation = require('./sample.validations');
let model = require('./sample.model');

//sample.js
module.exports = function (Sample) {
    model(Sample);
    validation(Sample);
};

//sample.model.js
module.exports = function (Sample) {
    console.log('log from model');
};

//Sample.validations.js
module.exports = function (Sample) {
    console.log('log from validations');
};
```